# Loading .txt file to textarea Java

Tags: java, text, jtextarea

I have a textarea that loads a specified file.  Everything works well except for that only the last line of the file is output into the textarea.

```
File f = new File(this.path);

try {
    // Create a Scanner for the file
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);

    // Read text from the file
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        jTextArea1.setText(input.nextLine());
    }

    // Close the file
    input.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
    fe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the only line to appear is the last one.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in your while loop you are setting the text, instead of appending to it.

So every time you get a new line of input you override the last one. You are eventually left with only the last line of input.

Use `jTextArea1.append(input.nextLine());` instead of `jTextArea.setText(...);`.

Comment: Youre right It was replacing the text after every line. Appreciate the comment

Comment: @user3424451 I was wondering to know if my way works too. can you try it ?

Comment: For sure, will try it out

Answer (score 1):

With a delimiter in `java.util.Scanner`, you can read the entire file and not line by line.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
input.useDelimiter("\\A");
if (input.hasNext()) {
    jTextArea1.setText(input.next());
}
```

See more in [*Stupid Scanner tricks...*](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner.html) for `useDelimiter("\\A")`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
jTextArea1.setText(input.nextLine());
```

With

```
jTextArea1.append(input.nextLine());
```

`setText()` replaces all the text in the textArea with the argument, `append()` adds to the text in the textArea

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to append all input together and setText with result of StringBuilder Varialbe at the end

```
File f = new File(this.path);
StringBuilder sb = StringBuilder();

    try( Scanner input = new Scanner(f)) {
        // Read text from the file
        while (input.hasNext()) {
           sb.append(input.nextLine());
        }
         jTextArea1.setText(sb);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        fe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note: you can use try catch block with resources after java 7, so there is no need to close scanner manually.

Read more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 0):

While most of the other answer are correct in pointing out the use of `setText` instead of `appendText`, the fact is, `JTextArea` has a convenient method for loading text

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("...")))) {
    ta.read(br, null);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which simplifies the entire process...